# Group according to a column in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have an csv file contains three columns, subject, predicate, object
I want to group the data according to subject column value and add rest data as list attached to subject (Dictionary) in python.

```
per_subject = defaultdict(list)
with open("C:\\Rasha\\Nema\CODES\\DataSets\\geocoordinates-fixed.csv",  mode='r') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header row
    for subject, predicate, object in reader:
        per_subject[subject.strip()].append([predicate.strip()])
```

The compiler of python give the following error:

> File "C:/Users/HP_Ra/PycharmProjects/ReadCSV/readCSV.py", line 10, in
>   
>       for subject, predicate, object in reader: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: [pandas `.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) ?

Comment: pls post a fragment of the csv file

Comment: your error is telling you there are more than three columns in your CSV btw...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some irregularity in the format of the data, one or more rows have more than 3 values. Easiest next step is to read the values not into a 3-tuple, but just into a list, and then unpack the list if it is the right size, else print it out for follow-up troubleshooting:

```
for row_num, row_list in enumerate(reader, start=1):
    if len(row_list) == 3:
        subject, predicate, obj = row_list
        per_subject[subject.strip()].append(predicate.strip())
    else:
        print("unexpected row size at row", row_num, ":", row_list)
```

Answer (score 9):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is well suited to this task as it can read the csv for you and comes with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) functionality:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

input_file = Path("C:/Rasha/Nema/CODES/DataSets/geocoordinates-fixed.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
# if the headers aren't right then:
# df.columns = ['subject', 'predicate', 'object']
df_per_subject = df.groupby('subject')['predicate'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
# And if you want a dict out
df_per_subject.to_dict()
```

Note that if this is going to be production code, pandas is a fairly heavy library to use for this. However, if you are looking for a quick fix to an ad-hoc problem, I personally find it to be worth the while.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195212/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-group-according-to-a-column-in-csv-using-python).